# Use Privatemsg admin form in theme (Missing functions!)

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, privatemsg

I've exposed the privatemsg_list_view() form in my site theme with a bit of work and it's displaying well. However, updating message statuses or trying to delete bulk messages results in a sad error:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred. 
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: Fatal error: Call to undefined function privatemsg_list_submit() in [...]/includes/form.inc on line 1464
```

Now I know that privatemsg_list_submit() is indeed set as the form #submit handler and I know that it *does* exist, over in `modules/privatemsg/privatemsg.pages.inc`. Obviously there is a disjoint between /system/ajax and my template.

What needs to happen to make this work? Do I just have to attach the .inc file to the form handler somehow? I've tried playing with module_load_include() to no avail.

Suggestions?

**Update**: The only place I have tried adding the `module_load_include()` function is directly before the function call in /includes/form.inc - that would have been somewhere just before line 1464. Obviously that was just a hack for troubleshooting purposes... should the `module_load_include()` function be placed somewhere else?

For reference: [Call to undefined function privatemsg_list_submit()](http://drupal.org/node/1961776)

**Update 2**: I have also tried inserting `module_load_include()` in a custom module_init() function as well as inside the theme `hook_form_alter()` - no luck.

**Update 3**: Manually including the file within a `module_init()` hook makes it work. Here's what it looks like:

```
function MYMODULE_init(){
    if($_GET['q'] == 'system/ajax'){        
        if ( preg_match('/privatemsg_list/', $_POST['form_id'])) {
            include('/great/big/system/path/web/sites/all/modules/privatemsg/privatemsg.pages.inc');
        }
    }
}
```

While this appears to work on the surface, I'm sure it's not the right method. Is there a better function hook to use to include this file?

Comment: `module_load_include()` is indeed the solution, could you add more information about what you've tried with that?

Comment: As per **Update**, I tried inserting it directly into `forms.inc`. Should this go in the view or the .tpl.php instead?

Comment: Can't get it to go from **Update 2** locations either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I suspect that this is an improper workaround, the solution was to hook a custom module's hook_init() function, watch for a system/ajax path and include the file if needed:

```
function MYMODULE_init(){
    if($_GET['q'] == 'system/ajax'){        
        if ( preg_match('/privatemsg_list/', $_POST['form_id'])) {
            include('/great/big/system/path/web/sites/all/modules/privatemsg/privatemsg.pages.inc');
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Answer is available at https://drupal.org/node/1961776! In short: use `form_load_include()` instead of `module_load_include()`.